# Updating AlertDialog with custom layout if button from custom layout is pressed

Tags: android, dialog

Is it possible to update the AlertDialog content if a button is pressed inside the custom layout?

AlertDialog with custom layout is shown!
The custom layout has six buttons.

I want to update the Title everytime one of the six buttons are pressed inside the custom layout.

Layout is like this:

**TITLE LINE**

Custom Layout with 6 buttons

**The 3 AlertDialog buttons**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, keep a reference to the AlertDialog and Button's OnClickListener should look like this:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    mDialog.setTitle("New Title");
}
```